# Reverse for 'show-advertisement' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['show_advertisement/(?P<normalad_id>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, django-urls

in views.py file

```py
def show_advertisement(request, normalad_id):
    advertisement = NormalAd.objects.get(NormalAd, pk=normalad_id)
    return render(request, 'CPAPP/show_advertisement.html', {'advertisement': advertisement})


def list_advertisements(request):
    advertisement_list = NormalAd.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'CPAPP/advertisements.html', {'all': advertisement_list})
```

in urls.py file

```py
path('list_advertisements/', views.list_advertisements, name="list-advertisements"),
path('show_advertisement/<normalad_id>', views.show_advertisement, name='show-advertisement'),
```

in advertisement.html file

```
{% extends 'CPAPP/only_base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {% for element in all %}
        <a href="{% url 'show-advertisement' normalad_id %}">{{element.advertisement}} </a><br/>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

in show_advertisement.html file

```
{% extends 'CPAPP/only_base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    {{ advertisement }}

{% endblock %}
```

in models.py file

```py
class NormalAd(models.Model):
    adType = models.CharField('Type of the Ad', max_length=200, null=True)
    advertisement = models.OneToOneField(Advertisement, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    location = models.CharField('Location', max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.advertisement.address
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: You aren't passing `normalad_id` into the template, and so it is treated as a blank string, which doesn't match the url definition.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that.